# How to use a phones fingerprint sensor as a bio metric(fingerprint) scanner

Tags: javascript, java, android, mysql

I am developing an android application that will validate candidates using the phone's fingerprint sensor as the scanner to compare with already stored fingerprints in a database. How do I go about this??

Answer (score 0):

Android's fingerprint capability is solely for authenticating the user against the device, both for standard unlock scenarios or for apps that want to reconfirm that the person holding the phone is an authorized user of that phone.

Notably, your app cannot get at the fingerprint data for comparison with other data sources.

It is possible that some devices from some manufacturers offer a proprietary fingerprint sensor API that you could use. You could also look into external fingerprint sensors, as I think such things exist.